# DataTable Bootstrap theme missing width: 100%

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I'm using DataTable and Bootstrap in my application.

DataTable comes with a Bootstrap theme.
As per the doc, we shall only include only one css, the one of the theme we want, in my case Bootstrap.

Issue :
- the Bootstrap theme is missing default DataTable css properties, like width 100% on a table.DataTable
- if I include both the default one and the Bootstrap theme one, I have 2 icons on my headers.

Has someone found a solution ?

Comment: Instead of including two files ,Try putting the missing CSS for data table in the existing theme file only...

Comment: Instead of including two files ,Try putting the missing CSS for data table in the existing theme file only...

Comment: yeah, that would be tweaking vendor files, I don't like this a lot... I was hoping there was another solution

Answer (score 0):

Without changing the css file of your vendor you can put CSS that you miss (and only those) in a your CSS file to add it. Otherwise you can add a style element in your page and insert in this item only css that you lack. There are more answers to your question depends on whether the operation you need to do is relevant and is used on many pages, or whether it is limited to one or a few pages and contains few values. In the first case it is better the first solution, in accordance with the second.